# Sliding a form so that it looks like an animation

Tags: c#

I want to slide a form from a given position A to B in a given timeframe. This has to look smooth for the human eye.

Of course I could try and calculate the distance the form has to slide, divide it by the timeframe*25 (25 FPS) and then move it accordingly. The problem is that the result won't be an integer for every case and I can't move for example 2.3 pixels.

Another solution could be to use the calculation from above and round down/up the value and calculate it again after moving the form. I just think this might be a little bit to heavy since I would have to adjust the timeframe after every move and do the calculation again and again.

I don't have any code available, this is just some theoretical thinking and I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Before anyone is asking, I don't want to slide the content of the form, I know there are some ways to do this, I want to move the whole form.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF. WPF does support sub-pixel positioning.

Comment: I believe you can move objects to floating point values.

Comment: The calculation takes a handful of nanoseconds.  This is not a problem.

Comment: This would be pretty trivial in WPF (i.e. transition, etc.) and you wouldn't even need to handle the calculations.

Comment: its winforms. @HansPassant ok if you say so... I'll give it a try. I just thought there would be a better way.